# Run Standard Deviational Ellipse Plugin on multiple layers in QGIS3

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I want to run the [Standard Deviational Ellipse Plugin](http://arken.nmbu.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/SDEllipse/) for multiple point layers (eg 100 layers).
If there is a batch process option in Standard Deviational Ellipse Plugin, it will be solved.

Can I use python?
Please let me know if there is a good way.

Comment: Will you use the same parameters for all layers? I mean, for example, "Yuill method" and "sqrt(2) correction" for all layers?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, That's right.